# Doubt in textbook in Probability And statistical inference Example 1.6.3

Tags: probability, statistics

In text book **Example 1.6.3**** Suppose that a random variable U has an associated non negative function f(u) defined as (1/2)<sup>u+1</sup> if u = 1,2,3,..., u if 0 < u < 1 , 0 elsewhere. Observe that

$$\sum_{u=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{2})^{1+u} + \int_{u=0}^\infty f(u)du = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = 1 *->(1)$$

and thus f(u) happens to be the distribution of U. This random variable U is neither discrete nor continuous.

I did not understand the equation (1) . Why that equation proves f(u) happens to be the distribution of U. And what does it mean to be `neither discrete nor continuous` ?

Comment: Who's the author of the book?

Comment: Because the sum/integral over the domain must be 1. This is one (necessary) property of a probaility distribution.  Here it is a **mixed distribution** (keyword).

Comment: @callculus42 Why Summation is added in equation ? Integration over 0 to infinity of f(u) is 1, why summation?

Comment: @littleO Nitis Mukhopadhyay

Comment: @BRUCE *"Integration over 0 to infinity of f(u) is 1"* No, it is assumed that this is $\frac12$.

Comment: @callculus42 What summation is doing there then?

Comment: @BRUCE It is the other, discrete part of the mixed distribution.